# C# download program freezes until finished

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with with my image downloading program. When I run it, it freezes until all of the images are downloaded. The labels change but picturebox doesn't and I can't even move the program.

```
foreach (Match m in ms)
{
    label3.Text = m.Value;
    mastercount++;
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = m.Value;
    try
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadFile(m.Value, @downloadDest + "\\"+ mastercount + ".jpeg");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        label3.Text = "Failed to download image" + m.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you not only download one file after another, you also wait a second between each download.

Comment: Of course it waits, it's a blocking operation and you have just one thread. Try DownloadFileAsyncTask and working with continuations.

Comment: with or without the thread it has the same problem. The only reason i put that was beacuse i was told it might help, but it didnt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your application is freezing is because of these lines:

```
 wc.DownloadFile(m.Value, @downloadDest + "\\"+ mastercount + ".jpeg");
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

You are running this code on the `Main Thread` or `UI Thread` so no user interface operations can be performed while the above code is executing.  In order to solve this you should look into threading.  A good start would be the `BackgroundWorker`

See below:

- [Background Worker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)
- [How to use BackgroundWorker in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152850/how-to-use-backgroundworker-in-c-sharp)
- [File Downloading with BackgroundWorker](http://path4tech.blogspot.com/2012/03/file-downloading-with-progress-bar.html)

See Also:

- [WebClient.DownloadFileAsync - Download files one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042258/webclient-downloadfileasync-download-files-one-at-a-time)
- [DownloadFileAsync multiple files using webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048154/downloadfileasync-multiple-files-using-webclient)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do this as a Forms app, this will be a lot easier if you do it as a Console app.  Console apps are generally easier to work without freezing and cross-thread access problems.

If you need to stick with a Forms app, the simplest solution is to replace `Thread.Sleep` with `Application.DoEvents`.  It'll still freeze while downloading each image, and there are other issues that `DoEvents` can cause, but if you just need a quick fix, this is the easiest option.

Comment: you can't display the images in the console

Comment: @FJam okay wasn't sure that displaying was a requirement.  Anyway the answer in my 2nd paragraph should still work for you in the Forms option.  One line code change can get you what you need.